# Appmeasurement and Cookie Combining Utility

Tags: adobe-analytics

I am trying to upgrade a page with rather old Adobe Analytics tracking code (H.27) to the current Appmeasurement code. The code is heavily customized and relies, amongst other things, on the Cookie Combining Utility.

This is explicitly [verified as compatible](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/plugins_support.html) by Adobe (and according to the change log has been since April 2014). However our installed version (0.37) of the plugin fails, and I have not been able to find an updated version.

"Failing" means I get an error message "s.ape is not a function"; apparently this is a part of the s_code that has been removed in Appmeasurement.js.

So I wonder: Is there either an updated version of the plugin, or something (maybe even built into the current tracking code ?) that does the same thing as the plugin ?

Comment: I procured this from ClientCare on 2015.03.30: http://pastebin.com/72z7Kmut

Comment: You're a lifesaver.  I put in a ticket with ClientCare but they aren't all that fast and I'm on a deadline. Thank you very much !